# Поиск похожих слов в больших объемах текста

Tags: алгоритм, строки, любой-язык, подстрока

товарищи! Встала предо мной такая задача: имеется, скажем, некий текстовый документ. Мне нужно определить количество вхождений в этом документе родственных форм определенного слова. Например, если у меня слово, скажем, «**фейерверки**», то в качестве вхождений должны учитываться «**фейерверк**», «**фейерверками**» и все в таком духе.

---

Пока что я прибегаю к примитивнейшему стеммингу (удаляю у первоначального слова приставку и окончание (по словарю известных мне таковых)) и далее ищу вхождения полученной подстроки. Так что хотелось бы спросить: есть ли более красивый вариант реализации подобного дела?

Comment: Боюсь, что задача ОЧЕНЬ нетривиальна. Например, вы не учитываете суффиксы. `Серенький` - `серый`. `Езда` - `уехал` - `(шестой) подъезд`. А еще есть чередование согласных `ученик` - `ученица`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Точно. Про суффиксы и чередующиеся я и забыл) Эх. Великий и Могучий хД А про «езда - уехал», такое можно не учитывать)